# Toggle dragging of Google Map markers once added as Draggable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a Google Map API v2 app, where markers are loaded from a database. These markers can then be dragged to a new location by a user and saved to the database.

I'm adding these markers as draggable, however I don't just want the users to be able to drag them accidentally. So I have added a button to enable the dragging and then press again to disable it.

Only problem is I'm not sure how I can toggle the ability to drag the markers without reloading them again, as there could be a few hundred markers on the map and may take some time.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be very easy to do. First you need to keep a reference to all your markers. Then to toggle the dragging behaviour, you can simply iterate through your markers and call the [`enableDragging()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.enableDragging) or the [`disableDragging()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.disableDragging) method on each marker.

For this to work, your markers will have to be initialized with the `GMarkerOptions.draggable` option set to `true`, but I assume you are already doing this.

Here's a fully working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()">
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <input type="button" value="Toggle Drag" onclick="toggleDrag()">

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      var point = new GLatLng(51.49, -0.12);
      var marker = new GMarker(point, { draggable: true });

      map.setCenter(point, 8);
      map.addOverlay(marker);

      function toggleDrag() {
        if (marker.draggingEnabled()) {
          marker.disableDragging();
        }
        else {
          marker.enableDragging();
        }
      }
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```